# 3 dimensional vector in c++ - partial definition of size before passing to function

Tags: c++, memory-management, resize, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

I would like to define a 3-dimensional vector of which the first two dimensions are fixed, but I'd want the third one to be dynamically filled by a function called inside a loop.

I am not completely sure whether this is allowed or not, but I have tried to implement it anyway with something like:

```
#define NUM 6

vector<vector<vector<double> > > foo;

foo.resize(NUM);
for(int j1=0; j1 < NUM; j1++){
    foo[j1].resize(NUM);
}

while(<condition>){
    fun(foo);
}
```

where I declare the function fun as

```
void fun(vector<vector<vector<double> > >& foo){
    for(int j1=0; j1<NUM; j1++){
        for(int j2=j1+1; j2<NUM; j2++){
             if(<condition>){
                   foo[j1][j2].push_back(<value>);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I initially tested this for NUM equal to 5 and everything looked fine, but when I've tried to change it to 6, I've got a segmentation fault.

I have seen that even if I don't try to fill in the 3rd dimension with the push_back (i.e. I comment the push_back line), the simple call to the function which has foo as an argument messes up the dimension of foo, that is if I insert a

```
  cout << foo.size() << endl;
```

in the while loop, I see that the dimension of foo changes after the first iteration, changing from NUM to a random number.

I've also found that this is platform dependent, as I'm getting the error on Linux Ubuntu, but not on MacOSX. So I guess I am doing something really wrong related to memory allocation, but I don't know exactly what. Could someone explain this to me?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what happens if you comment out the whole loop and just try to do `cout<<foo.size()` from `fun`? Also, can you post the exact condition you have used in `while(<condition>)` in the calling function? And you have recompiled everything after changing NUM from `5` to `6` (i.e. some code is not compiled using `NUM` as `5` and some other code compiled using `NUM` as `6` right?)

Comment: Do you have a simple standalone example where the problem is present? Your code as is (aside from the inner for loop in `fun` - which I assume is intentional) looks okay.

Comment: This code should be valid as posted. You must post an SSCCE.

Comment: @Naveen I've tried to comment the while loop and called foo.size() within the function, and it becomes immediately a random number, so I don't think the while loop is to blame. 
I have a makefile that includes all the code so I think everything is recompiled at the same time.

Comment: @Nim what's with the inner for loop? It may be something really stupid I am not seeing. 
I'll try to write down a standalone example, but it'a bit complicated. I really thought I was making some kind of conceptual error here!

Comment: This is **not** a 3-dimensional vector. It's a triply-nested `std::vector`, which does roughly (but not quite) correspond to a 3-dimensional _array_.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. It wasn't actually in this part of the code but in the initialization of one of the other arguments of `fun`. I have no idea why this ended up messing up my `foo` vector as well, but anyway...!
Thank you all for helping me with this!

Comment: @leftaroundabout oops, sorry. What's a 3-dim vector like then?

Comment: For me, a 3-dimensional vector is an element of a mathematical vector space that has dimension 3. You'd represent that with a simple array with 3 elements, e.g. `std::array<double,3>`. In the context of C++ `std::vector`s, "3-dim vector" doesn't really make sense at all. These are a bit of a misnomer anyway, they're simply dynamical arrays, so nesting them implies that each of the elements may have different dimension. That's not what you want here, consider making a class that emulates a 2-dimensional array in a single `std::vector` and fill that with `std::vector<double>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create a 3D matrix of a fixed number size with 2D matrices also of desired size using a vectors constructor that takes as an argument the number of elements and an element that it'll use to make copies of to fill in the vector. Here's how it'll look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const size_t NUM = 6;
    std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > Matr(NUM, std::vector< std::vector<double> >(NUM, std::vector<double>()));
    std::cout << "num 2D matrices - " << Matr.size() << std::endl;
    for(size_t j1 = 0; j1 < Matr.size(); ++j1){
        std::cout << "num rows - " << Matr[j1].size() << std::endl;
        for(size_t j2 = 0; j2 < Matr[j1].size(); ++j2) {
            Matr[j1][j2].push_back(0.09l);
            std::cout << "num columns - " << Matr[j1][j2].size() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.resize(NUM);  
for(int j1=0; j1 < NUM; j1++){  
    foo[j1].resize(NUM);
}
```

here you are resizing `foo[j1]`, but there is nothing in `foo[j1]` yet..
so `foo[j1]` is just a garbage yet.

Comment: shouldn't this be ok? How else could I declare the two dimensions that I know already?

Comment: no..its not.. `foo.resize(NUM)` will create a `NUM` default vectors, so `foo[j1]` is completely valid.

Comment: oops~ missed it...It should be Ok then

Comment: You could also remove the for-loop and use a vector<vector<double> > with size NUM as second parameter to foo.resize. Don't think that'll fix your original problem though. ;)